# PHP retrieving from SQL database?

Tags: php, sql

I'm really stuck on this question, I have given it my all and I still cant work out whats wrong, even my friends have attempted to help me, I'm beginning to think its unsolvable... Here's what is wants

Create a PHP script, named task3a.php, that retrieves the names and id of each driver, and outputs the
information differently to the previous two tasks. Instead of displaying a table, the output should contain
an HTML form. The form should contain a submit button and a drop-down list input. The drop-down
input should contain the driver names, and the form should submit via the GET method to task4.php
when the submit button is pressed. Name the select input driver.

And here's what I've got -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTMl>
<html>
<body>
<?php
try { 
$dbhandle = new PDO('mysql:host=<...>.ac.uk;dbname=user','user','pass');
} catch (PDOExeption $e) {
die('Error Connecting to Database: ' . $e->getMessage());
}


$driver = 'SELECT forename, surname, d.nationality, name FROM Drivers d JOIN Teams t ON d.id = t.id';
$query = $dbhandle->prepare($driver);

if ($query->execute() === FALSE ) {
die('Error Running Query: ' . implode($query->errorInfo(), ' '));
}

$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Forename</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Team</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['forename']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nationality']; ?><td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<form action='task3a.php' method='GET'>
<select name=''driver>
<?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
<option value='<?php echo $row['id'];?>' > <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's giving me a table with everything in it at the moment and then under it a drop down box with nothing in it, I'm so confused

Comment: "PHP my SQL form" is not a question

Comment: You are using `$row['id']` but not selecting id from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $query->fetchAll();
       ^--- no S
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                     ^---no S
<?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
                     ^----where did this S come from?
```

Comment: Thanks that definitely helped :) In terms of the question do you think that should be fine or would I have to add a submit button as well?

Comment: it's usually good practice to provide one. not everyone will know to hit enter to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing this

```
<select name=''driver>
```

to

```
<select name='driver'>
```